# Language detection caught in loop

Tags: javascript

I've created a basic language detection function for a website that redirects the user to either the English or Spanish (default) version of the site depending on their browser language.

```
const url = window.location.href;
const getLang = () => {
    return /^en\b/.test(window.navigator.language) ? "en" : "es";
}
document.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (!(/es\b/.test(url)) && !(/en\b/.test(url))) {
        window.location.href = url + getLang();
    }
}
```

The script seems to work just fine when tested on a local server, but on [the website itself](https://epicbounties.com/) the script constantly redirects the user back to the same landing page, causing a frustrating loop. Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Maybe you need to insert a delimiter when you concatenate `url` and `getLang()`?

Comment: first solve (/es\b/.test(url)), it returns true because the name of the site contains an es "epicbounties"

Comment: I don't get redirected at all, not sent into a loop. Note that `epicbounti_es_.com` alone matches `/es\b/` already.

Comment: @AntonioTorres Yeah I caught that as well and solved it.

Comment: @Bergi see the above comment on the regex issue. I did a little tinkering with the order of the scripts which solved the loop issue, but the JS doesn't seem to be running at all now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I did some tinkering in the HTML of the page with the ordering of the scripts which ultimately seemed to solve the looping issue.
2. I noticed an issue with the regex in the `if` statement within the `document.onreadystatechange` (which was also pointed out by [@AntonioTorres](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10438586/antonio-torres) and [@Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi)). Given that the website's domain is "epicbounties.com", it returned a positive for the `/es\b/.test(url)` regex, so I had to change that to `/\bes\b/.test(url)` to isolate the language between two non-word characters and return a negative.

Following these fixes, the script then didn't seem to be running at all when the page loaded, but after a little while it suddenly was; possibly could be a rendering issue on GitHub Pages' side, but I can't wrap my head around it at all. In any case, I'm just glad it's working as intended now.

Answer (score 0):

If I execute `window.location.href` in this page we are now, I get:

```
window.location.href
// "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67612205/language-detection-caught-in-loop"
```

Your function `getLang` returns either `"en"` or `"es"`.

In your event handler, you are trying to redirect to:

```
window.location.href = url + getLang();
// "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67612205/language-detection-caught-in-loopen"
```

In summary, you need a `/` so separathe the path.

Comment: When the script runs on the root page (i.e. "stackoverflow.com"), the `/` is appended automatically with `window.location.href`. I don't believe that's what's causing the issue.

Comment: Can you place a breakpoint and confirm? Or check in the Developer Tools's Network tab?
If that us the case, I will remove the answer